# substitute a letter at a specific position in the file itself using bash

Tags: bash, position, uppercase

I am trying to do this:

I have a file with content like below;

file:
abcdefgh

I am looking for a way to do this;

file:
a**BC**defgh

So,make the 2nd and 3rd letter "**capital/uppercase**" **in the file itself**, because I have to do **multiple conversions** at different positions in a string in the file. Can someone please help me to know how to do this?

I came to know something like this below, but it does only for a single first character of the string in the file:

```
sed -i 's/^./\U&/' file
```

output:
Abcdefgh

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your **sed** approach to the following:

```
sed -i 's/\(.\)\(..\)/\1\U\2/' file
```

---

```
$ cat file
aBCdefgh
```

---

*matching* section:

- `\(.\)` - match the 1st char of the string into the 1st captured group
- `\(..\)` - match the next 2 chars placing into the 2nd captured group

*replacement* section:

- `\1` - points to the 1st parenthesized group `\1` i.e. the 1st char
- `\U\2` - uppercase the characters from the 2nd captured group `\2`

---

**Bonus** approach for *I want to capitalize "105th & 106th" characters*:

```
sed -Ei 's/(.{104})(..)/\1\U\2/' file
```

Comment: `^` is redundant, first match starts from left and `.` will always match first char

Comment: Thanks! can you please help me understand the command? :-). For example; I do not get how only "bc" were capitalized.

Comment: @Dipak, see my explanation

Comment: Thanks! Let's say I have a very long string "200" characters of "a-z" in the "file". I want to capitalize "105th & 106th" characters. Could you please let me know how can I achieve that using sed command above? Thanks much! :-)

Comment: @Dipak, check bonus solution

Answer (score 1):

awk on duty.

```
echo "abcdefgh" | awk '{print substr($0,1,1) toupper(substr($0,2,2)) substr($0,4)}'
```

Output will be as follows.

```
aBCdefgh
```

In case you have a Input_file and you want to save the edits into same Input_file.

```
awk '{print substr($0,1,1) toupper(substr($0,2,2)) substr($0,4)}'  Input_file  > temp_file && mv temp_file  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Please run above code as this is only for explanation purposes.

```
echo "abcdefgh"  ##using echo command to print a string on the standard output.
|                ##Pipe(|) is used for taking a command's standard output to pass as a standard input to another command(in this case echo is passing it's standard output to awk).
awk '{           ##Starting awk here.
                 ##Print command in awk is being used to print anything variable, string etc etc.
                 ##substring is awk's in-built utility which will allow us to get the specific parts of the line, variable. So it's syntax is substr(line/variable,starting point of the line/number,number of characters you need from the strating point mentioned), in case you haven't mentioned any number of characters it will take all the characters from starting point to till the end of the line.
                 ##toupper, so it is also a awk's in-built utility which will covert any text to UPPER CASE passed to it, so in this case I am passing 2nd and 3rd character to it as per OP's request.
print substr($0,1,1) toupper(substr($0,2,2)) substr($0,4)}'
```

Comment: Short and concise. I like it!

Comment: @MatiasBarrios, your are welcome. Thanks for encouragement.

Comment: Thanks! can you please help me understand what the command is doing?

Comment: @Dipak, could you please check now and let me know if this helps you.